# SearchPane.QuerySubmitted - What is the proper way to route to App.xaml.cs vs Individual Xaml Classes

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

So, I am finding that users are a bit confused with using charms and would rather have an in-App button that they can press/click to do searches.  I prefer to use the SearchPane method as it has all the built in processes for handling search history hints.

So, in App.xaml.cs, I have this:

```
    protected override void OnWindowCreated(WindowCreatedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Register QuerySubmitted handler for the window at window creation time and only registered once
        // so that the app can receive user queries at any time.
        SearchPane searchPane = SearchPane.GetForCurrentView();

        searchPane.QuerySubmitted += new TypedEventHandler<SearchPane, SearchPaneQuerySubmittedEventArgs>(OnQuerySubmitted);
        searchPane.SearchHistoryEnabled = true;
    }
```

So this sets up an event so that when the general search is performed, it calls an Event handler for OnQuerySubmitted also in App.xaml.cs to handle whether the search charm is used for that particular context.  Roughly, I look for a file to be open, if no file is open no search is allowed and give a MessageDialog indicating this.

However, in other xaml pages I want the choice of a search charm or an xaml defined button that will manaully open the SearchPane (I know some of the code is redundant):

```
    private void GoSearch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Enable the search pane and the 
        SearchPane searchPane = SearchPane.GetForCurrentView();
        searchPane.SearchHistoryEnabled = true;

        // Register QuerySubmitted event handler
        searchPane.QuerySubmitted += new TypedEventHandler<SearchPane, SearchPaneQuerySubmittedEventArgs>(OnQuerySubmitted1);

        // Show the search pane
        searchPane.Show();
    }
```

But I am finding, not surprisingly, that when each page is traversed through, I am getting more and more Event Handlers created.  So one search ends up getting tons of handlers called.  I don't like this, but without taking handlers off when a page looses context, I don't know what else to do.

I would seem better if I can make the App.xaml.cs call a function in the current page's xaml code behind.  But I am unsure if this is possible unless I declare a bunch of static member functions.  Which also seems less than optimal.

Any suggestions on the proper approach here?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [Event Aggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xx130644.aspx) to send messages to any part of your UI by subscribing to a message type and it will be notified when a message of that type is published. This will require you to use the Prism library from Microsoft but that library can also provide a lot of other benefits to your app.

Answer (score 0):

I chose an even sleazier path....

```
    private void OnQuerySubmitted(object sender, SearchPaneQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Get frame information about the currently visible window. 
        Frame frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // If the current frame is not valid, do not continue
        if (frame == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Based on who the base frame is, call the process query handler for the proper frame....
        if ((typeof(A.MainPage) == frame.CurrentSourcePageType)
        {
           // do something
        }
        else if ((typeof(A.MainPage2) == frame.CurrentSourcePageType)
        {
           // do something
        }

        // and so on
```

Not the best way, and causes me implementation every time I add a frame, but there are worse things in the world....